# More than one Free shipping issue with Shopping Cart Pricing Rule If General Free Shipping Enabled?

Tags: attributes, free-shipping, magento1.9.2.3

I have applied free shipping for purchase over 1000,

[image]

If i try for free shipping specific products which is below 1000 using **Shopping Cart Price Rule**  Free shipping not applying,

[image]

Note : Created free shipping attribute and inside the products page enabled,

[image]

How to enabled free shipping for specific products even general free shipping currently active?

Note : I am using **Webshopapps Matrix Rates**

Comment: You have chosen for the specific country...Have you tried for a specific country you have selected in the list

Comment: Yes, i am tested with the country what i selected in the list.

Comment: have you checked free-shipping attribute value is set to Yes for items added in cart? As there is a condition that "Free Shipping is Yes"

Comment: Yes, i checked -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh3Jz.png

Comment: @zus you have all items to apply this rule or specific items?

Comment: @RakeshDonga Specific Items

Comment: @zus please share screenshot which items you are added in catalog rule

Comment: @RakeshDonga I have created attribute and assigned to the product which i need free shipping and selected free shipping attribute https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh3Jz.png

Comment: @zus you have checked your created attribute is working ? when rule save after

Comment: @RakeshDonga my attribute 1) https://snag.gy/mSafek.jpg   2) https://snag.gy/QEM7P1.jpg   3) https://snag.gy/Hks7IY.jpg    & in the product page https://snag.gy/KAOam1.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93326/discussion-between-zus-and-rakesh-donga).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93327/discussion-between-zus-and-rakesh-donga).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **Free Shipping Promotions** from Webshopapps Matrix Rates extension's system configuration.

Please check below links for more information:

http://support.webshopapps.com/matrixrate/free-shipping-promotions/
http://support.webshopapps.com/premium/creating-free-shipping-promotions/

Hope this will help you.